# ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment XXXXXXXX by 8192 in tablespace USERS

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I get the below error when I try to insert data in the database.

```
ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment XXXXXX by 8192 in tablespace USERS
```

I'm using an Oracle database (`express 12c` version). Googling the error I found that it means that there no more space in the tablespace and you need to increase the dimension of your datafile or the number of datafile you are using. I have 5 datafile of 30 GB and one of them is empty so I don't understand what the problem is.

**Edit**

```
SYSTEM      793,19      800     99,15   32768   2,42

SYSAUX      2203,56     2320    94,98   32768   6,72

UNDOTBS1    48,13       23345   0,21    32768   0,15

USERS       153534,5    30720   499,79  30720   499,79

USERS       153534,5    30720   499,79  30720   499,79

USERS       153534,5    30720   499,79  30720   499,79

USERS       153534,5    30720   499,79  30720   499,79

USERS       153534,5    30720   499,79  30720   499,79
```

Answer (score 3):

paste the results of the following

```
select d.tablespace_name "TS",
   (select round(sum(s.bytes/(1024*1024)),2)
      from dba_segments s
      where (s.tablespace_name = d.tablespace_name)
      group by s.tablespace_name) "Used",
round(d.bytes/(1024*1024)) "FSize",
round((select sum(s.bytes/(1024*1024))
  from dba_segments s
  where s.tablespace_name = d.tablespace_name
  group by s.tablespace_name)*100/(d.bytes/(1024*1024)),2) "% Used",
round(maxbytes/(1024*1024)) "MAX FSize",
round((select sum(s.bytes/(1024*1024))
  from dba_segments s
  where (s.tablespace_name = d.tablespace_name) AND (d.AUTOEXTENSIBLE = 'YES')
  group by s.tablespace_name)*100/(maxbytes/(1024*1024)),2) "% Used of MAX"  from dba_data_files d;
```

Comment: as mentioned by @Giovanni above you need to find which tablespace you Lobs are stored in as that is the tablespace you will need to add more data files to. Looking at the output you provided, all the datafiles in the USERS tablespace look full (although the format has gone a bit strange so i stand to be corrected)

Comment: Yes it seems they are full. I don't know why Oracle enterprise manager show that one datafile is empty (fully allocated but empty)

Comment: just remember there is an 11gb max database size in express edition (at least there is in 11g and i assume the same to be true in 12c)

Comment: there is no size limitation 12g

Answer (score 2):

Each tablespace (a logical entity) maps to one or more o.s. file (even on raw device or something different on some installations). One file may belong to only one tablespace.

If you have more than one tablespace you may have a lot fo free space in other tablespace but you may not use it.

You can enlarge you data file oo change the tablespace where your table indexes are located.

Your specific error is related to lob (i.e. blob or clob); may be you are inserting a lot of/large binary objects that fill the tablespace; you can "allocate" the lob segment in a different tablespace.

If you are just experimenting I suggest to enlarge the data file, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles003.htm#ADMIN11423) for instructions

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query in your sys to alter the tablespace as per your requirement.

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/scratch/...../SCHEMA_NAME.dbf' RESIZE 5G;
```